# Laravel on a directory, links e.g. login link does not work

Tags: laravel, webserver, hosting, laravel-5.3

I have uploaded my Laravel app unto a directory under the public folder on my domain,

> html_docs/public/store

where 'store' is the folder of my Laravel App. My main domain pointed at 'html_docs/public', please check my laravel app here "https://www.dinhi.org/store/". As you can see, when you click the "sell with us" or "login" on the top header, it returns

```
Not Found

The requested URL /store/dashboard/login was not found on this server.
```

I have set up to in my '.env' and in my 'config/app.php' the right url like "https://www.dinhi.org/store/" but still not working, any ideas, help please?

PS: I'm on Laravel 5.3 and I'm using [Hesto Multi Auth](https://github.com/Hesto/multi-auth). In my local, this issue does not exist like everything is good and working.

Comment: Could you give more details? How is the app hosted? Which web server are you using? One easy way to isolate if this issue is related to webserver is to run "php artisan serve" in the server on a port like 8000 and see if the application is working correctly

Answer (score 0):

Laravel is not meant to be installed completely into the document root of your server. Actually, every folder of your laravel application except the `public` folder should be inaccessible from the web.

Your exposing yourself to a security risk here, since everybody could access every file of your app, including potential `.env` files with database credentials and the likes.

Cheers

Christoph